Is there a way to check if 128-bit integers are available
I'm working on a fixed-point math library. The accepted way of handling multiplications for fixed-point numbers is to multiply them into an integer variable that's larger than what you're storing, then shift the result to the right based on the scale factor.
The thing is, I'm already using 64-bit integers for storage, so in order to be able to multiply two values, I'm going to need access to a 128-bit integer. Otherwise, I'm going to have to split each value into two 32-bit integers and multiply them separately. (Either that, or do something creative with std::bitsets; I haven't decided yet.)
In other words, I need to do something like the following pseudocode:
typedef int64_t storage_t;

if (type_exits(int128_t)) {
    typedef int128_t math_t;
    const bool use_32_bit_algorithm = false;
} else if (type_exists(__int128)) {
    typedef __int128 math_t;
    const bool use_32_bit_algorithm = false;
} else {
    typedef int64_t math_t;
    const bool use_32_bit_algorithm = true;
}

How do I implement type_exists()?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Originally, I had gone with the option suggested in the comments of checking which compiler was being used, then typedef whatever that particular compiler called its 128-bit integer. Then, I found a much better answer, entirely by accident, when I was looking up something else.
The answer is to switch to the C++23 standard, which allows me to use the new _BitInt keyword to just make up an integer of whatever size I want, and let the compiler handle it. So, now my code looks something like this:
using value_t = int64_t;
int constexpr max_bits_math = std::numeric_limits<value_t>::digits * 2;
using math_value_t = _BitInt(max_bits_math);
int constexpr bit_shift = 8;

value_t operator*(value_t lhs, value_t rhs) {
    math_value_t answer = static_cast<math_value_t>(lhs) * static_cast<math_value_t>(rhs);
    return static_cast<value_t>(answer >> bit_shift);
}

Yes, I know that not a lot of compilers support _BitInt yet, because it's so new. Then again, I'm still in the very early stages of this project, so I'm confident support will be more widespread when I'm ready to release.

FWIW: CppReference includes _BitInt in its list of C Keywords, but omits it from its list of C++ Keywords.

C++ specifies that if the implementation defines a type called std::int128_t, then <cstdint> must define a corresponding macro INT128_MAX:

Each of the macros listed in this subclause is defined if and only if the implementation defines the corresponding typedef-name.

However, if a 128-bit integer type is provided by a non-Standard name, then the Standard imposes no requirements, and you're then reduced to compiler-specific ifdefs.  And then I would recommend you bug your compiler authors to provide their types via the standard interface.

This is a relatively recent LWG issue fix. Previously there wasn't any possibility for these 128bit typedefs/macros. And the reason that std::int128_t isn't going to be used is that this would acknowledge the 128bit type to be an extended integer type in the sense of the standard and then std::intmax_t must also be at least as large. Changing std::intmax_t would however be an ABI break.

I guess if your std::intmax_t is less than 128 bits, then you'd want to save that change for your next ABI break, true.  Just in case some maniac passes that as function argument or return.

Actually, no - I just looked it up, and it seems that std::int128_t is allowed to be wider than std::intmax_t, which doesn't need to accommodate bit-precise integer types or extended integer types that are wider than long long: 7.22.1.5  I think that diminishes the value of std::intmax_t, but I guess it was a compromise worth making.

This is also a recent development. Before C23 the wording doesn't have these exceptions and the new wording isn't yet incorporated into C++. (u)intmax_t is a long-standing issue. You can find a lot of papers on the topic in the WG14 document log. I have not kept up on this, so I don't really know whether or how this was resolved in the end. Maybe in the future it will be possible to actually see non-default fixed-bit-width integer types implemented.
